# IE9/IE10 - Transparency Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a page where I have a div that is positioned over another div. The top div is set to be transparent in most places, and not capturing pointer events. I know IE 9 and 10 don't support the CSS pointer-events property, but I'm seeing some odd behavior in IE 9 and 10 when the underlying div doesn't have any content. In those cases, it doesn't grab the mouse events at all. If there's a border or some text content hovering over the border or content does work, but not in the blank spaces of the element. I've tried using the transparent background image, but that doesn't seem to work. I've attached the link to the bare-bones fiddle that reproduces the problem.

HTML:

```
<div class="topElement"></div>
<div class="bottomElement">Works in IE 9 and 10 only if you hover over text or border.</div>
```

CSS:

```
.topElement {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 2;
}
.bottomElement {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background: transparent 0 0 repeat scroll url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBR??AA7");
}
.bottomElement:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MLundin617/jpr3j8jb/4/

The area should turn red when you hover over it.

Answer (score 1):

You must write `z-index` to `".bottomElement" >=2`

Comment: But I don't want it to be. I want it to be on the bottom. In my actual page, there is some areas of the "topElement" that have content, and that needs to show.

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle that has an element in the top div the must appear on top. http://jsfiddle.net/MLundin617/jpr3j8jb/10/ In Chrome and Firefox, everything turns red unless you're over the "itemOnTop" in which case only that item turns blue. In IE 9 and 10, the red only happens if you're over the text or the border.